# Xcode 14.2 - Annoying source control shadow changes

Tags: xcode, git

Hi All not sure if anyone is having this but when making changes it adds the blue box on the left-hand side which is fine as before this was just showing what had changed. Now though, it's added this discard change and gives you a kind of before and after within your code. It's really really annoying and difficult to make changes. I've added a screenshot here where I was just removing so spacing. The code doesn't appear to do anything until you commit. Turning off Source Control completely doesn't even get rid of it.

Does anyone have any solutions for just turning this silly feature off completely? I've always used git fine with no issues within Xcode,  I don't need to see the old change just what I'm actually updating the code to be.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that after reverting changes whitespaces become tabs or vice versa (Xcode has settings to use either whitespaces or tabs for indentation)?

Comment: yeah its doing for everything so if removing code for example,  it wont actually remove it just highlights and adds that annoying blue box on the left..... must be a setting though somewhere i would have thought and it wasnt doing this before the update

Comment: You turn it off completely in Xcode settings , Xcode -> Settings -> Source Control

Comment: yeah turned off and had to actually reboot the macbook to force the change so obviously something not right. Its a horrible feature really and if you click inside the block that you are trying to remove, Xcode crashes......  wont be turning that back on in a hurry

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer to my comment (or you didn't understand my comment.) What I meant is that indentation can be set by means of whitespace symbols or tab symbols in Xcode settings (Xcode -> Preferences -> Text editing -> Indentation -> Prefer indent using.) If, for example, there are tabs in your code and whitespaces in Xcode settings, after re-formatting the line, whitespaces are changed to tabs, and Git consider it a change (which it is indeed.) So, I suggested checking if it's the case.

Comment: I understood fine, it wasnt this lazarevzubov

Answer (score 0):

Your "Code Review" is on. The issue disappears if you turn it off

[top right corner of the editor window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRHsP.png)